# Have I ruined my chicken by marinating it in milk and lemon?

Tags: chicken, milk, marinade

So I wanted to make Gordon Ramsay's buttermilk fried chicken [Recipe](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CYgvXXLb6EU). Although I didn't have any buttermilk so I found online you can use milk with lemon as a replacement for buttermilk. Sounded perfect. Gordon recommends in the video that you marinade it over night. So I try that. I have come back the next day and the milk has separated. Have I ruined the chicken?

Thank you in advance.

EDIT: Yes its been in the fridge. very little lemon juice was included, so it doesn't appear to have cooked.

EDIT 2: OK, I will try it and then answer my own question with the result.

Comment: Does the chicken appear to have 'cooked' a bit?

Comment: Was it in the fridge?   If so should be safe to cook.

Comment: @Dorothy very little lemon juice was included, so it doesn't appear to have cooked

Comment: @Paparazzi Yes it was in the fridge.

Comment: Then it should be fine (too much lemon/acid without oil can toughen meat).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would be surprised if your milk didn't curdle. The entire point of adding the lemon is to induce this to at least a certain extent. Buttermilk is already somewhat curdled so as long as it wasn't so acidic that the chicken was chemically cooked, everything should turn out fine.